# Selenium chrome PHP webdriver (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Have a selenium test in docker which suddenly stopped working

In logs it shows

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\UnknownErrorException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has 
crashed.)
```

I logged into the container and manually installed **google-chrome-stable** (90.0.4430.85-1) and **chromium-chromedriver** (90.0.4430.72-0ubuntu0.16.04.1)

When launching Chrome it gives the error

```
Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180.
```

I then launched it with --no-sandbox flag, but now it returns

```
[264:264:0424/105210.655665:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1386)] Unable to open X display.
root@9a0073021ee5:/usr/bin# [0424/105210.664350:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(307)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
```

I tried all of the possible suggested flags like `["no-sandbox", "headless", "disable-gpu", "disable-dev-shm-usage"]`

But it doesn't work.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Has nothing to do with Ubuntu that's inside the docker container, issue is somehow related to the Docker Desktop running on windows which starts these containers in the first place. Identical Docker setup but on a linux machine works just fine. Will open another ticket based on this info.